# Need a formula for Google Sheets to pull information from one sheet into another

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to create a google excel sheet that will populate student names into cells based on what room they have chosen for rewards day. Students will pick the room they will go to in a google form.  Right now I have 2 sheets made up. Sheet 1 is the spreadsheet information from the google form, and sheet two is the Room Sheet with columns that have been labeled with each available room. So if they pick the scrapbooking room, then I want to pull their name from Sheet 1 into the Room Sheet under the scrapingbooking column. Is this even possible? I'm assuming I'll need a formula for each room choice...at least that is what I am thinking...but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Try [vlookup()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318) or [xlookup()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947). Both can be evaluated over many rows with [arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093275). Please [edit] your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.